# Brownie Request for Random number (Mock VRF) reverts

Tags: solidity, remix, blockchain, brownie, chainlink-vrf

Using chainlink tutorial and concept for testing a random request locally, Request Randomness fails to execute in brownie for VRFCoordinatorV2Mock, however, I tested the same code in remix IDE and it works perfectly when manually requesting a random number using the mock version[image]. What could be the issue with brownie? someone help me address this. Thanks